# Yii Check if entry exists in database before creating new one

Tags: database, oop, model, yii

I'm pretty new to yii.

I have a form that creates and saves multiple AR models to the database. The problem is that in many cases new entries are actually identical to existing ones. I would like to reduce/ eliminate this kind data redundancy.

**The form has 3 entities:**

```
  - the main model
  - client model
  - product model
```

Many times, product and client will already exist in the database.
Product and Client are referenced through foreign keys in the main model.

**I want to know how would it be possible to do the following:**

- as I type a client's name or phone number, yii searches in the client table and display results as suggestions, through ajax.
- if I select one of the suggestions, the Client AR should be populated with that database entry.
- when the form is submitted:

  - if an existing client was selected, use that client's id inside the main model. Do not create a duplicate client in the database.
  - if client wasn't found in the existing records, create a new one    with the provided form data.

I apologize for the bad formatting, this is my second time posting a question. If I wasn't very clear in what I am looking for, please ask for clarification. This is something I would really like to learn.

Comment: Hm, and what did you try? I just googled "yii ajax fill dropdown" and found dozens solutions.

Comment: I managed to find a way around my problem. Still not the solution i initially wanted, but it will do. I gave up on the ideea of suggestions and auto completing necessary fields. And just had the model check if the entry exists before creating a new one. If it does, it will use that entry's id.

Comment: @bksi Of course I used google, then the yii documentation and then the yii forums before posting here. I'd thank you but you weren't of much help, mate.